# Does the inequality $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha} \geq \vert u(x)\vert^{\alpha_1}$ hold for some constants $\alpha, \alpha_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u, v:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions. Let $\alpha\geq 1$. There is a relation between $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha}$ and $\vert u(x)\vert, \vert v(x)\vert$, maybe to some power?
I mean, does some inequality of the type
$$\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha} \geq \vert u(x)\vert^{\alpha_1},$$
or
$$\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha} \geq\vert v(x)\vert^{\alpha_2},$$
hold for some coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$?

To be clear, $( u(x), v(x))\in\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert$ denotes the modulus of the vector $(u(x), v(x))$.

Could anyone help or give some references?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess it might depend on the norm. For a $p$-norm, you have $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_p\ge \max\{\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert\}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. thank you, could you give me a reference? Do you mean I also could write $$\int_{\Omega} \vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha} \geq \max\left( \int_{\Omega} \vert u(x)\vert dx, \int_{\Omega} \vert v(x)\vert dx\right)^{\alpha}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\left|\binom{a}{b}\right|_{\ell^p}$ for the $\ell^p$ norm on vectors $\binom{a}{b}$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Note $|a|^2 \le |a|^2 + |b|^2 = \left|\binom{a}{b}\right|_{\ell^2}^2$. Thus
$$ |a| \le \left|\binom{a}{b}\right|_{\ell^2}.$$
Exchanging the role of $a,b$ we get
$$ \max(|a|,|b|) = \left|\binom{a}{b}\right|_{\ell^\infty} \le \left|\binom{a}{b}\right|_{\ell^2}. $$
If you want $a=u(x)$, $b=v(x)$ to vary as a measurable function of $x\in\Omega$, we clearly get for any $\alpha \in [0,\infty).$
$ \int_{\Omega} \left|\binom{u}{v}\right|_{\ell^\infty}^\alpha dx \le \int_{\Omega} \left|\binom{u}{v}\right|_{\ell^2}^\alpha dx   $. The above inequality is nothing more than a special case of the inclusion (true for dimensions $\le \infty$)
$$ 1 \le p < q \le \infty \implies \ell^p \subset \ell^q.$$
This can be found in any introductory book on functional analysis.